# Gravitational wave or "pure gauge"?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gravitational-waves, diffeomorphism-invariance

Given the following linearized metric tensor ($c=1$)

$$h_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & f(t-z) & 0 & 0 \\
    f(t-z) & 0 & 0 & -f(t-z) \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -f(t-z) & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$

how can one know whether it describes a gravitational wave or a "pure gauge"?

Comment: Is $h$ some linearised metric? What you want to show is that $h$ is "pure gauge", i.e. can be set to 0 by a gauge transformation?

Comment: Yes, $h_{\mu\nu}$ is a linearised metric. And yes, I want to show it is a "pure gauge".

Comment: Simple. Calculate the Riemann Tensor. If it the part linear in h vanishes then the perturbation is pure gauge.

Comment: @mmeent, if the Riemann tensor does not vanish, why does $h_{\mu\nu}$ represent a gravitational wave (GW)? In the case $h_{\mu\nu}$ does not depend on time, certainly it is not a GW.

Comment: You said you wanted to show that it was pure gauge. This is true if and only if the Riemann tensor vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a linearised perturbation of Minkowski spacetime
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$
where $|h_{\mu\nu}|\ll1$. 
Consider a diffeomorphism $\phi_{t}$ generated by a vector field $X$:
$$(\phi_{-t})_{*}(g)=g+\mathcal{L}_{X}g+\ldots=\eta+h+\mathcal{L}_{X}\eta+\ldots$$
where the ellipsis denotes higher order quantitites. From this you deduce that $h$ and $h+\mathcal{L}_{X}\eta$ describe physically equivalent spacetimes. In other words, linearised GR has the gauge symmetry $$h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu}+\partial_{\mu}X_{\nu}+\partial_{\nu}X_{\mu}.$$
The question you are asking is whether $h_{\mu\nu}$ can be set to zero by a gauge transformation, i.e. if there exists an $X$ such that
\begin{align}
h_{01}+\partial_{0}X_{1}+\partial_{1}X_{0} &=0\\
h_{13}+\partial_{1}X_{3}+\partial_{3}X_{1} &=0\\
\partial_{2}X_{3}+\partial_{3}X_{2} &=0\\
\partial_{0}X_{3}+\partial_{3}X_{0} &=0\\
{\rm etc...}
\end{align}

If such an $X$ exists, then $h$ is *pure gauge*.

In fact, you can show that 
$$X=-F(t-z)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
where
$$ F'(Z)=f(Z)$$
is a solution to the above.

Comment: I have been playing around with the set of PDEs, but till now I was not able neither to find a solution nor to prove $X$ does not exist. Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess $X=F(t-z)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$ with $F'(t-z)=f(t-z)$ should do the job?

Comment: Actually, it should be $X=F(t-z)\partial_{x}$. I will edit the answer

Comment: In that case, we have (1) $\partial_t F(t-z)=-f(t-z)$ and, on the other hand, (2) $\partial_z F(t-z)=f(t-z)$. Now, if tou apply $\partial_z$ to (1) or $\partial_t$ to (2), you conclude $\partial_t\partial_zF(t-z)$ must be zero.

Comment: What do you mean by $F'(Z)=f(z)$? What does the prime stand for?

Comment: it means that $f$ is the derivative of $F$. $f$ and $F$ are functions of one argument. The prime stands for derivative w.r.t. that argument. I don't understand your comment. Why do you have second derivatives?  What are you trying to show?

Comment: The vector field I wrote has only one non-zero component: $X^{1}=-F(t-z)$. Take the first equation of the system: $0=h_{01}+\partial_{0}X_{1}+\partial_{1}X_{0}=f(t-z)+\partial_{t}F(t-z)=f(t-z)-F'(t-z)\partial_{t}(t-z)=f(t-z)-F'(t-z)$ and so on...

Comment: You are right. $X=F(t-z)\partial_x$ works.

Comment: Cool. If that answers your question, can you mark the answer as accepted? Cheers